# acrobat pdf - characters UTF8 encoding in xfdf data

Tags: pdf, utf-8, acrobat, xfdf

The solution looks like this:

1. There is a submit button below the form in PDF file.
2. Submit button is sending XFDF form data through POST.
3. When I generate (in PHP) XFDF file from POST data polish characters encoded in UTF8 are messed up.
4. When you populate XFDF file back into PDF characters are OK.

The question:
What Adobe Reader is doing to correctly display this messed up UTF8 characters?

How to do it in PHP on server side to have proper UTF8 data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by messed up? Maybe you simply aren't aware of the encoding used for sending that request...

Answer (score 0):

Everything was in UTF8. XFDF files, database connection and tables.

The problem was with PHP settings.

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL', 'pl', 'Polish_Poland.28592');

And problem solved.